# What the symbol || means in electronics

Tags: circuit-design

I'm reading some texts (single supply circuits collection) about circuits and I encounter the symbol ||.

What is the meaning of it?

For an example in a circuit about an op-amp circuit that provides gain i see in the "inverting" description:

Gain = -R2/R1

R3 = R1||R2

(I can't insert a schematic, circuit editor never starts)

Comment: Parallel. 
(15char)

Comment: R1 and R2 resistors are connected in parallel combination.

Comment: More precise: Two resistors act in parallel combination (rather than saying: They are in parallel). Is there a difference? Ohh yes, because it depends on the nodes you are speaking of. When two resistors have a common node, the act in series as far as the resistance between both open ends are considered. And the act in parallel if you are measuring between the common point and the (connected) other two nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means you take the parallel combination of the resistors, rather than the series value which would easily be written R1+R2.

Frequently when we use a resistive divider with two resistors R1 and R2, it's also important to know the effective impedance of the tapping point. This is given by R1||R2. From your example, it sounds like R3 is balancing the voltage drop of a bias current, that's also flowing from the tap point of R1 and R2.

I find it's easier to do the sum \$\frac{R1.R2}{R1+R2}\$ in my head, whereas on a calculator \$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2}}\$ tends to be easier. They are equivalent.

Comment: Followup question: Is there a similar symbol for series? I've often wanted to discribe a network in this textual form but have had issues. Ofcourse, for resistors it's just a sum, but if you have circuits with capacitors as well, this is no longer true.

Comment: @JorenVaes yes, with caps, it's tricky. I don't know whether there's any accepted symbol. Where a have a capacitive voltage divider and write the nodal impedance, I still write ||, but implement it as the sum, which is correct for caps. Where caps are in series, say in a Colpitts, I think I tend to use words.

Comment: I see, guess I'll have to find my own notation then.

Comment: I use the same notation as for resistors, but use the correct formulas for capacitors. To communicate with others, I usually draw a small schematic, to be on the safe side, as I can see it will create trouble.